# Int:Splitter is not sending messages to channels to invoke them

Tags: spring-integration

I am trying send message from int-file:inbound-channel-adapter to int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter for moving file to remote directory and int-ftp:outbound-gateway to delete file in remote directory.

Now int-file:inbound-channel-adapter polls and sends message to int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter and when it polls second time sends message to int-ftp:outbound-gateway.

By using int:splitter i am still able to receive single message for single file and only one channel is getting invoke. I want to send every poll message to both channels.

Example follows:

***Now working as:***

1. First time polls sends message to int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter
2. Second time polls sends message to int-ftp:outbound-gateway
3. Third time polls sends message to int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter
4. Fourth time polls sends message to int-ftp:outbound-gateway

***Want to achieve as***:

1.First time polls sends message to int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter and int-ftp:outbound-gateway
2.Second time polls sends message to int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter and int-ftp:outbound-gateway

Thanks in advance

```
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="inErrorINPRm"
                                channel="errorRm" 
                                directory="in/error"
                                >
    <int:poller fixed-rate="5000" />
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:channel id="errorRm"></int:channel>
<int:channel id="ErrorRmMv"></int:channel>
<int:channel id="ftpINPfromError"></int:channel>

<int:splitter id="splitter" input-channel="errorRm" output-channel="ErrorRmMv"/>

<int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter id="ftpError"
                                channel="ErrorRmMv" 
                                session-factory="ClientFactory"
                                auto-create-directory="true"
                                remote-directory="in/error"
                                >
</int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter>

<int:header-enricher id="header-enricher-error" input-channel="ErrorRmMv" output-channel="ftpINPfromError">
    <int:header name="file_remoteDirectory" value="in/working"/>

</int:header-enricher>

<int-ftp:outbound-gateway id="gatewayRmfromError"
                          session-factory="ClientFactory"
                          expression="file_remoteDirectory"
                          request-channel="ftpINPfromError" 
                          command="rm" 
                          >
</int-ftp:outbound-gateway>
```

Answer (score 0):

The splitter has nothing to split - the payload is already a single `File`.

Splitters are for splitting, say, a list to a message for each list element.

You need to make the input channel for the adapter, and header enricher a `<int:publish-subscribe-channel/>` - you can add `order="1"` to the adapter and `order="2"` to the enricher, to make it clear the order in which they are called.